# spring trying to load environment variable

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a question about trying to inject an environment variable into my spring mvc controller.

I have an environment variable as follows...

POS_MANAGER_SERVER_REPORTING=myserver

In my spring application context I have ...

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:systemPropertiesModeName="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"
    p:searchSystemEnvironment="true"/>

<bean name="posManagerController"
    class="com.mycompany.reporting.controller.PosManagerController"
    p:posManagerServer="${POS_MANAGER_SERVER_REPORTING}" />
```

When I do not define the system variable in websphere the application does not start up properly. When I add the variable it does. But for some reason the value being injected into my controller is null.

Can someone help me with what might be going wrong here? i.e. Why the environment variable is not loaded properly?

Just to give you some more information, the Controller is loaded in the child context (-servlet.xml) using the @Controller annotation but in the parent context (applicationContext.xml) I also have the controller defined as appeared above. My understanding is that spring is smart enough to be able to handle this. I've listed this information just in case this might be the cause of the issue.

thanks

Comment: Can you show the `posManagerServer` part of you Controller?

Comment: And why do you have that controller in both contexts? You really should only keep the `-servlet.xml` part and take care of that `posManagerServer` there (with `@Value` or similar).

Comment: Andrei, using @Value can I get an system environment variable?

Comment: See my comment from my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-extension-factory-postprocessors):

> Also, BeanFactoryPostProcessors are scoped per-container. This is only relevant if you are using container hierarchies. If you define a BeanFactoryPostProcessor in one container, it will only be applied to the bean definitions in that container. Bean definitions in one container will not be post-processed by BeanFactoryPostProcessors in another container, even if both containers are part of the same hierarchy.

So, you need a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in `-servlet.xml` file to make it work.

Comment: You need `@Value("${POS_MANAGER_SERVER_REPORTING}")
 private String posManagerServer;` in your `PosManagerController` and the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in `-servlet.xml`